# Every time I add a Ad Hoc app to my iTunes replaces my other ad Hoc app

Tags: iphone, adhoc

I don't know where to look for about this problem ...

I have three Apps, and when I want to add to iTunes, I can add the first one.

When I want to add the second one, it says it exists and if I want to replace it ...

Sure there must be some unique name or id, but I can't find it ...

I have a valid:

- Developer certificate
- Distirbution certificate
- Ad Hoc provisioning

Any help appreciated ...

thanks,

r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine your apps are both using the same Application Bundle ID. You'll need to use different bundle IDs so that iTunes can see that they are different apps.

To change the bundle ID, get info on your application target and go to the properties tab and change the ID in the Identifier field.

Note that any app id's and provisioning profiles that this app uses should use the same bundle ID. Wild card app IDs don't work for adhoc apps.

Comment: You're right as I have the same Identifier for all apps.

So I must have a diferent provisioning ad hoc for any App that I want to use as a ad hoc ?

Comment: That is correct. Bundle IDs need to be unique for different apps, or else iTunes and the iPhone will think the apps are the same and overwrite them.